# Can't attach angularjs service to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm getting this error when I try to attach a service to a controller:
[$injector:unpr] ... webSocketServiceProvider <- webSocketService <- videoMenuCtrl

I have a plunker defined with a fairly minimal setup that reproduces the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ptaIaOhzOIG1mSi4bPyF?p=preview

Here are the main culprit files:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="videoApp">
    <section class="menu" ng-controller="videoMenuCtrl">
    </section>
    <script src="webSocketService.js"></script>
    <script src="videoMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="ngDialog.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ngPopup.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webSocketService.js:

```
(function(angular) { 
    'use strict';

angular.module('videoApp')
    .factory('webSocketService', function($q) {
    return{};
});
});
```

videoMenu.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('videoApp', ['ngDialog', 'ngPopup']);

app.controller('videoMenuCtrl', function($scope, $window, $location, ngDialog, webSocketService) {

});
```

I don't get an error if I remove the webSocketService from the controller, but the point is to have the controller be able to access the webSocketService.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Edit: Changed file name typo.

Comment: When do you import the `videoMenuCtrl.js` file? If it is the same as `videoMenu.js`, you need to load this file before `webSocketService.js` since the latter uses the module defined in the former.

Comment: My typo.  videoMenuCtrl.js should be videoMenu.js.  (I will have edited it).  I originally had videoMenu.js listed before webSocketService.js in my index.html but changed it around because videoMenu refers to webSocketService so I figured it needed to be first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code working. Two things I noticed:

1. In you `webSocketService.js` you were re-declaring the `videoApp` module.
2. You were declaring the module inside a function expression that was not being invoked.

I re-declared your service in a properly namespaced module and wrapped it in an [immediately invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

I also removed your `var app =` declaration from your `videoMenuCtrl` and wrapped it in an IIFE as well. This is to avoid cluttering the global namespace. Here is a working plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/A8BcATiaqhXCA7BZDXWx?p=preview

**EDIT** (*clarification*) The IIFEs are not strictly necessary in my example plunk because the `var app =` declaration was removed from the code. That was the only variable that was being declared on the global namespace in the original example. *However*, wrapping the code in IIFEs has no negative effects as far as I know.

Comment: Normally one would also load the popup and dialog dependencies before injecting them into the app. And all the wrapping in IIFE's is totally unneccesary because there are no global vars being declared.

Comment: Is `var app = angular.module('videoApp', ['ngDialog', 'ngPopup']);` not a global variable declaration (in OP's example), or were you referring to my plunk?

Comment: Yes i was referring to your plunk, since you removed app variable you can remove the IFFE also.